# How do I execute spark submit job with python3/python2 mypthon3.zip compiled zip on databricks DRE 7.6 and above?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-submit

I am trying to execute spark submit job with python3 and python2 compiled mypthon3.zip on Databricks DRE 7.6 and above and getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dbfs/tmp/WT_SPARK3/Inputsql.py", line 1, in <module>
    from com.test.mymodule import Mymodule
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'com'
```

**mypython3.zip** : compiled with python3 and contains pyc file with pycache folder

**command to compile** : python3 -m compileall -b package_dir

```
mypython3.zip
  |- com
      |- __pycache__ (empty folder)
      |- __init__.pyc
      |- test
           |- __pycache__ (empty folder)
           |- __init__.pyc
           |- mymodule.pyc
```

**Inputsql.py**

```
from com.test.mymodule import Mymodule
import sys
import time
import logging
```

**spark submit command**

["--py-files","/dbfs/tmp/mypthon3.zip","/dbfs/tmp/Inputsql.py"]

Please let me know how to fix it

Thanks